# dmesg log dump help

Tags: unix

I keep having dumps in my dmesg logs, I suspect that it's the NIC making errors. Can someone give me their opinion?

After this happens, I can't access the machine through the network.

```
[28965.681498] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.681504] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.681506] Call Trace:
[28965.681509]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.681524]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.681529]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.681532]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.681538]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.681542]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.681545]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.681548]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.681552]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.681568]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.681575]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.681581]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.681586]  [<ffffffff8022f669>] ? default_spin_lock_flags+0x9/0x10
[28965.681590]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.681595]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.681599]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.681602]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.681605]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.681608]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.681611]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.681613]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.681622]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.681625]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.681630]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.681632] Mem-Info:
[28965.681634] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.681636] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.681638] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.681640] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.681644] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.681645]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.681646]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.681650] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.681653] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.681660] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.681664] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.681668] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.681678] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.681687] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.681689] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.681691] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.681692] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.681694] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.691482] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.691482] 2481 pages shared
[28965.691482] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.691482] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.691482] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.691482] Call Trace:
[28965.691482]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.691482]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.691482] Mem-Info:
[28965.691482] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.691482] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.691482] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.691482]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.691482]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.691482] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.691482] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.691482] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.691482] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.691482] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.691482] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.691482] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.691482] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.691482] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.691482] 2481 pages shared
[28965.691482] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.691482] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.691482] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.691482] Call Trace:
[28965.691482]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.691482]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.691482] Mem-Info:
[28965.691482] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.691482] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.691482] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.691482]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.691482]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.691482] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.691482] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.691482] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.691482] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.691482] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.691482] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.691482] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.691482] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.691482] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.691482] 2481 pages shared
[28965.691482] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.691482] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.691482] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.691482] Call Trace:
[28965.691482]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.691482]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.691482]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.691482] Mem-Info:
[28965.691482] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.691482] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.691482] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.691482] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.691482]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.691482]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.691482] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.691482] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.691482] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.691482] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.691482] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.691482] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.691482] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.691482] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.691482] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.691482] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.691482] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.691482] 2481 pages shared
[28965.691482] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.731188] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.731193] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.731195] Call Trace:
[28965.731197]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.731210]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.731214]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.731217]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.731223]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.731226]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.731230]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.731233]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.731237]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.731251]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.731258]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.731265]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.731270]  [<ffffffff8069b0d1>] ? _spin_lock_irq+0x11/0x20
[28965.731274]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.731279]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.731283]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.731287]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.731290]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.731293]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.731296]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.731298]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.731307]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.731310]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.731314]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.731316] Mem-Info:
[28965.731318] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.731320] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.731322] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.731324] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.731328] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.731329]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.731330]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.731334] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.731337] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.731343] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.731347] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.731351] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.731361] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.731370] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.731372] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.731374] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.731376] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.731377] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.741084] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.741084] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.741084] 2481 pages shared
[28965.741084] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.743621] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.743626] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.743628] Call Trace:
[28965.743630]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.743642]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.743645]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.743648]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.743654]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.743658]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.743661]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.743664]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.743668]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.743683]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.743689]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.743696]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.743701]  [<ffffffff8069b0d1>] ? _spin_lock_irq+0x11/0x20
[28965.743705]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.743709]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.743714]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.743717]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.743720]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.743724]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.743727]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.743729]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.743737]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.743740]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.743744]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.743747] Mem-Info:
[28965.743748] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.743751] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.743752] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.743755] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.743759] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.743760]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.743761]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.743765] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.743768] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.743774] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.743778] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.743781] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.743791] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.743801] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.743802] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.743804] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.743806] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.743807] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.753521] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.753521] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.753521] 2481 pages shared
[28965.753521] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.755988] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.755993] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.755995] Call Trace:
[28965.755997]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.756009]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.756012]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.756016]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.756022]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.756026]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.756030]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.756033]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.756036]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.756051]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.756057]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.756063]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.756069]  [<ffffffff8069b0d1>] ? _spin_lock_irq+0x11/0x20
[28965.756073]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.756077]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.756082]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.756086]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.756089]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.756092]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.756095]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.756097]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.756105]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.756109]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.756113]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.756115] Mem-Info:
[28965.756117] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.756120] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.756121] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.756123] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.756127] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.756128]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.756130]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.756133] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.756137] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.756143] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.756146] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.756150] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.756160] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.756169] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.756171] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.756173] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.756175] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.756176] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.765895] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.765895] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.765895] 2481 pages shared
[28965.765895] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.768467] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.768472] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.768474] Call Trace:
[28965.768476]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.768489]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.768492]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.768496]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.768501]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.768505]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.768508]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.768511]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.768515]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.768529]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.768536]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.768542]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.768547]  [<ffffffff8069b0d1>] ? _spin_lock_irq+0x11/0x20
[28965.768551]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.768556]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.768560]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.768564]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.768567]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.768570]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.768573]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.768575]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.768583]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.768586]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.768590]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.768592] Mem-Info:
[28965.768594] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.768596] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.768598] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.768600] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.768604] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.768605]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.768606]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.768610] DMA free:6580kB min:12kB low:12kB high:16kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB present:5536kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
[28965.768613] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3257 3257 3257
[28965.768619] DMA32 free:2652kB min:7292kB low:9112kB high:10936kB active_anon:46580kB inactive_anon:16636kB active_file:16296kB inactive_file:3133764kB unevictable:0kB present:3335492kB pages_scanned:66 all_unreclaimable? no
[28965.768623] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
[28965.768626] DMA: 3*4kB 3*8kB 3*16kB 5*32kB 3*64kB 2*128kB 3*256kB 2*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 6580kB
[28965.768636] DMA32: 313*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 0*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 2612kB
[28965.768647] 788265 total pagecache pages
[28965.768649] 0 pages in swap cache
[28965.768650] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[28965.768652] Free swap  = 6385796kB
[28965.768654] Total swap = 6385796kB
[28965.778363] 849664 pages RAM
[28965.778363] 24304 pages reserved
[28965.778363] 2481 pages shared
[28965.778363] 821207 pages non-shared
[28965.780975] swapper: page allocation failure. order:0, mode:0x4020
[28965.780979] Pid: 0, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.28-16-server #55-Ubuntu
[28965.780982] Call Trace:
[28965.780984]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff802b6c5e>] __alloc_pages_internal+0x3ee/0x4f0
[28965.780996]  [<ffffffff802dfc28>] alloc_slab_page+0x28/0x30
[28965.780999]  [<ffffffff802e0cea>] new_slab+0x5a/0x210
[28965.781003]  [<ffffffff802e2308>] __slab_alloc+0x188/0x290
[28965.781008]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.781012]  [<ffffffff802e3217>] __kmalloc_track_caller+0xd7/0x110
[28965.781015]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] ? __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.781019]  [<ffffffff805a97ae>] __alloc_skb+0x6e/0x150
[28965.781022]  [<ffffffff805a9b0f>] __netdev_alloc_skb+0x1f/0x40
[28965.781038]  [<ffffffffa00634a4>] e100_rx_alloc_skb+0x34/0x1e0 [e100]
[28965.781045]  [<ffffffffa006388b>] e100_rx_clean+0xbb/0x280 [e100]
[28965.781051]  [<ffffffffa0064eee>] e100_poll+0x2e/0xd0 [e100]
[28965.781056]  [<ffffffff8069b0d1>] ? _spin_lock_irq+0x11/0x20
[28965.781060]  [<ffffffff805b3924>] net_rx_action+0x104/0x240
[28965.781066]  [<ffffffff80256bec>] __do_softirq+0x9c/0x170
[28965.781071]  [<ffffffff80213d8c>] call_softirq+0x1c/0x30
[28965.781074]  [<ffffffff80214ffd>] do_softirq+0x5d/0xa0
[28965.781077]  [<ffffffff8025696d>] irq_exit+0x8d/0xa0
[28965.781080]  [<ffffffff802152c5>] do_IRQ+0xc5/0x110
[28965.781084]  [<ffffffff80212bf3>] ret_from_intr+0x0/0x29
[28965.781085]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff8021a95a>] ? mwait_idle+0x4a/0x50
[28965.781093]  [<ffffffff80210dd2>] ? enter_idle+0x22/0x30
[28965.781097]  [<ffffffff80210e85>] ? cpu_idle+0x65/0xc0
[28965.781101]  [<ffffffff806871bc>] ? rest_init+0x5c/0x70
[28965.781103] Mem-Info:
[28965.781105] DMA per-cpu:
[28965.781107] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
[28965.781109] DMA32 per-cpu:
[28965.781111] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 115
[28965.781115] Active_anon:11645 active_file:4074 inactive_anon:4159
[28965.781116]  inactive_file:783441 unevictable:0 dirty:39634 writeback:2 unstable:0
[28965.781117]  free:2308 slab:8374 mapped:611 pagetables:765 bounce:0
[28965.781121]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a warning message, not necessarily an error.  It is produced by linux-2.6.32/mm/page_alloc.c function __alloc_pages_slowpath() and delivered at "warning" level.

The code fragment from that function that produces the message is:

---

```
nopage:
    if (!(gfp_mask & __GFP_NOWARN) && printk_ratelimit()) {
            printk(KERN_WARNING "%s: page allocation failure."
                    " order:%d, mode:0x%x\n", p->comm, order, gfp_mask);
            dump_stack();
            show_mem();
    }
    return page;
```

---

The mode:4020 is an indicator that these two flags are set, see linux-2.6.32/include/linux/gfp.h

```
#define __GFP_COMP      ((__force gfp_t)0x4000u)/* Add compound page metadata */
#define __GFP_HIGH      ((__force gfp_t)0x20u)  /* Should access emergency pools? */
```

GFP is Get Free Pages

For GFP_COMP see ``what is "compound_page()" all about?''
http://www.spinics.net/lists/newbies/msg41151.html

I re-asked this question but all differently as "Is __alloc_pages_slowpath() Reentrant-Safe or Not?"

Answer (score 2):

It's just ENOMEM at the kernel level.  Install more memory, or increase your swap size.

Answer (score 1):

As womble said, it means a memory allocation failed. But the network shouldn't fail after that, so it may be a bug in the e100 driver you seem to be using.